# How to pass dynamic value to the firebase cloud function using stripe payment in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment gateway in my React Native App using firebase cloud functions. Now i am facing a problem regarding passing the dynamic values to string PaymentIntent like amount and currency.

Here is my code

```
exports.paymentSheet = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req", req);
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create();
  const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
      {customer: customer.id},
      {apiVersion: "2020-08-27"},
  );
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 2000 * 100,
    currency: "usd",
    customer: customer.id,
  });
  res.json({
    paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
    customer: customer.id,
  });
});
```

The above function is a firebase cloud function i have to pass a dynamic value to amount and currency, but i am not able to do that.

Here is the code where i am fetching the response in my other component:

```
const response = await fetch(
            'https://domainName/paymentSheet',
            {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
              body: formData,
            },
          );

          const { paymentIntent, ephemeralKey, customer } = await response.json();
          setCustomer(customer)
          setClientSecret(paymentIntent);
          return {paymentIntent, ephemeralKey,customer};
```

Comment: You need to pass some parameters with your `formData` value that can be then used with your Stripe API calls. What is `formData` in this instance?

Comment: formData is an object having all the required information like price and currency

         const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('price', 8766);
          formData.append('currency', 'usd');

Comment: Those parameters will be available in your function on the request object, specifically `req.body`. Is there a particular reason why you're using FormData as opposed to JSON?

Comment: @JonathanSteele Can you please explain a bit more because i am not getting it through req.body.

Comment: When you `console.log(req.body)` in your `paymentSheet` function, what is the contents?

Comment: @JonathanSteele there is a attribute in body with name "price".

Comment: Then you can pass the `price` variable to the `amount` parameter when calling `stripe.paymentIntents.create`.